# Running Svelte app with 'npm run dev' works, but nothing is on the localhost

Tags: npm, startup, svelte, svelte-component

When I run `npm run dev` then my project works, but can't access it from localhost. This is what I keep getting in the log:

```
[20:57:56] 200 ─ 7.93ms ─ /
[20:57:57] 404 ─ 0.22ms ─ /bundle.css
[20:57:57] 404 ─ 0.19ms ─ /bundle.js
[20:57:57] 200 ─ 21.38ms ─ /global.css
[20:57:58] 404 ─ 0.22ms ─ /favicon.ico
```

This is what I Have in package.json:

```json
"dev": "rollup -c -w",
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have to be on a specific port such as localhost:8080. Are you getting an error when you try to go to localhost or are you getting a blank white screen?

Comment: Are your files correct case sensitivities? On Windows you could get away with this mistake, but on Linux Bundle.css, bundle.css, bundle.CSS and bundle.Css are completely different files.

Comment: I go to the localhost and I get a blank page.